# Blueimp jQuery File Upload and my exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, blueimp

I want to pass error message to Blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin. I use ASP.NET MVC and throw my own exception when some conditions are appeared (i.e. file is not real image, only image exception or image is too wide etc).

```
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                _service.ImageValidation(file.InputStream);

    public void ImageValidation(System.IO.Stream fileStream)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(fileStream, false);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new NoImageException();
        }
        if (bmp.Width > bmp.Height && (bmp.Width < 1024 || bmp.Height < 768))
            throw new ImageDimensionTooSmall();

        if ((bmp.Width <= bmp.Height) && (bmp.Width < 768 || bmp.Height < 1024))
            throw new ImageDimensionTooSmall();

        fileStream.Position = 0;
    }
```

on client side I try to catch error by the following way:

```
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: '/SmartphonePhotographer/ManageFiles?ResponseID=' + ResponseID,
            error: function (e, data) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

'data' variable always has 'error' value. 'e' has many properties, including statusText='Internal server error' and responseText (html page with exception). Question - how can I pass error message on server side to catch it on client side (maybe, there is an json format for errors, but I did not find it in documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes to the error event because you are throwing an exception in your server side code. So the ajax call is getting a 500 internal error response.

What you can do is, instead of throwing an exception, return a json response with the error messages.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveImage()
{
   if(IsFileNotValid())  //your method to validate the file
   {
      var customErrors = new List<string> {"File format is not good",
                                            "File size is too bib"};
      return Json(new { Status = "error", Errors = customErrors });

   }
   //Save/Process the image
   return Json ( new { Status="success", Message="Uploaded successfully" });
}
```

And in the `done()` event, you can inspect the json response and show the error messages as needed.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/SmartphonePhotographer/ManageFiles?ResponseID=' + ResponseID,
    error: function (e, data,txt) {
        alert('error' + txt);
    }
}).done(function(response){
   if(response.Status==="error")
   {
       $.each(services.Errors, function (a, b) {
         alert(b);
       });
   }       
});
```

With this approach, you can send multiple validation errors back to the client and client can process(show to user ?) it.

**MVC 6**

In MVC6, you can return an HttpStatusCode response directly from the MVC controller action. So no need to send a JSON response yourself.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult SaveImage()
 {
     var customErrors = new List<string> { "File format is not good", 
                                            "File size is too bib" };

     return HttpBadRequest(customErrors);
 }
```

This will send a 400 Response to the caller with the data we passed(the list of errors) in the response. So you can access the responseJSON property of your error xHr object of the `error` event to get it

```
error: function (a, b, c) {           
     $.each(a.responseJSON, function (a, b) {
            alert(b);
     });
 }
```

Comment: I'd give you an up vote if you set the response code to bad request... that would force the uploader to go into the error block.  I'm not a fan of forcing people to check booleans for success/failure because most frameworks cue off of http status code.

Comment: I think he wants to send his custom error message(s) in a json format so that he can display it to the user. I am not sure sending just a bad request response will help.

Comment: but this control requires json in format https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/JSON-Response . But in anyway, thank you :)

Comment: @Nix You are correct, In MVC 6, we can return a Status code response (with custom response) from an action method ( like we did with Web api's earlier).

Answer (score 1):

I agree your issue is that you are throwing an exception versus returning a controlled response.   Most frameworks look for status codes in the 400x or 500x.  So you want to return a friendly json object and a status code in those ranges.  If you do that your data object in the error block will be what you returned.

**MVC Land:**

```
//get a reference to request and use the below.
return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Your message here");
```

**Web Api 2**

Use an `IHttpActionResult` and return `BadRequest("My error message");`  If you do that it will set your status code and return the response as the data.

Comment: return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Your message here"); - where did you find HttpResponseMessage constructor with 2 arguments? :)

Comment: Might have been a brain fart i think in older versions of mvc you could do that... maybe 4?  But either way you can use  `CreateResponse` to achieve the same.